# Unable to run selenium on Cpanel; selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, centos, cpanel

Selenium version: 4.8.2

OS: CentOS v7.9.2009 STANDARD standard

Cpanel Version: 108.0.14

I am using this code

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=8833")
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()), options=chrome_options)
```

and facing this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/vplaid/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/111.0.5563/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Please provide the error-message when you execute `/home/vplaid/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/111.0.5563/chromedriver` in your shell console.

Comment: Trace/breakpoint trap

Comment: Shell, not Python console